# Dropdown with Codeignitter and Bootstrap in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem to display database content in a dropdown. This is the code. Please give me a solution

**Models m_admin.php**

```
    public function getSiteList(){
       $result = array();
       //$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Table_Site ORDER BY ASC");
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from('Table_Site');
       $this->db->order_by('siteName','ASC');
       $array_keys_values = $this->db->get();
        foreach ($array_keys_values->result() as $row)
        {
            $result[0]= '-Select Site-';
            $result[$row->siteName] = $row->siteId;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

This is the Controllers (**admin.php**)

```
public function company()
  {
    if($this->session->userdata('isLogin')== FALSE)
    {
      redirect('login/login_form');
    }else
    {
      $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
      $data['level'] = $this->session->userdata('level');  
      $data['pengguna'] = $this->m_login->dataPengguna($user);
    }

    $this->load->model('m_admin');
    $data['site_list'] = $this->m_admin->getSiteList();

    $this->load->view('css/header');
    $this->load->view('css/topnav',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/adminmenu');
    $this->load->view('admin/companylist');
    $this->load->view('css/js');
    $this->load->view('css/footer');
  }
```

And this is the view (**companylist.php**)

```
<?php
foreach($site_list as $each){ ?>
<option value="<?php=.$each['siteId']?>"><?php=$each['siteName']?></option>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: The dropdown can't display the content of siteName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing and storing in a way which is different than what you are retrieving. Change your model code to

```
$count = 0;
$result = array();
$result[$count] = array("siteId" => 0, "siteName" => '-Select Site-');
foreach ($array_keys_values->result() as $row)
    {
        $result[++$count] = array("siteId" => $row->siteId, "siteName" => $row->siteName);
    }
```

Basically, you are not storing your siteId and siteName in the way you want it to be retrieved.

Also, you are wrong on how the result should be echoed. Change your view to

```
<?php
foreach($site_list as $each){ ?>
<option value="<?= $each['siteId'] ?>"><?= $each['siteName'] ?></option>
<?php }?>
```

`<?= $variable ?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo $variable ?>`. Also, the dot operator you used while echoing too is irrelevant

*(PS: Not tested, but should work and also should give you an idea on how to proceed)*